# List Component - Change gap size between cells

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I want to increase the gap size between cells in my list so they won't be on top of each other. I know there is `m_list.setStyle("contentPadding", 5)` but that only adjusts the gap from the edges of the list and not the individual cells. Also adjusting the rowHeight on the list does not effect the gap between adjacent cells. I can't seem to find any resources on how this is done.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's not support with api. You may create own List extends fl.controls.List and use trick with rowHeight, see down:

```
package 
{
    import fl.controls.List;
    import fl.controls.listClasses.CellRenderer;

    public class MyList extends List
    {

        public var gap:Number = 5;

        public function MyList()
        {
            super();

            rowHeight +=  gap;
        }

        override protected function draw():void
        {
            super.draw();
            updateRenderer();
        }

        protected function updateRenderer():void
        {
            var renderers:Array = availableCellRenderers.concat(activeCellRenderers);
            var l:uint = renderers.length;

            for (var i:uint=0; i<l; i++)
            {
                var renderer:CellRenderer = renderers[i];

                if (i > 0)
                {
                    renderer.y +=  gap;
                }

                renderer.setSize(availableWidth+_maxHorizontalScrollPosition,rowHeight - gap);

                renderer.drawNow();
            }
        }
    }
}
```